# How to open app only with domain or domain with certain path in Android ? using Android AppLinks

Tags: android, flutter, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I want to open the android app only with `domain` or `domain/journal`

So I added `domain/journal` in the `intent-filter` it works fine but

I want to open my app if the link is only the `domain`

eg. If `www.somedomain.com` user clicks the url it should open the app

```
   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.somedomain.com" android:pathPrefix="/journal" />
            </intent-filter>
```

- [www.somedomain.com](http://www.somedomain.com) => App Should open
- [www.somedomain.com/journal/.](http://www.somedomain.com/journal/.). => App should open